# Sinch PushKit isn't working

Tags: sinch

When I test my VoIP cert with a 3rd party client like Pusher, `didReceiveIncomingPushWith` works. But when I call using Sinch, it doesn’t.

I followed the docs to ensure that I have push set up properly, and have the corresponding `SINManagedPushDelegate` setup as well:

```
sinchWrapper.shared.push = Sinch.managedPush(with: SINAPSEnvironment.production)
sinchWrapper.shared.push.delegate = self
sinchWrapper.shared.push.setDesiredPushTypeAutomatically()
sinchWrapper.shared.push.registerUserNotificationSettings()

func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate pushCredentials: PKPushCredentials, forType type: PKPushType) {
    print("PUSH CREDENTIALS")
    print(pushCredentials.token.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined())
    print(pushCredentials.token)
    sinchWrapper.shared.client.registerPushNotificationData(pushCredentials.token)
}

func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("Getting push")
    sinchWrapper.shared.client.relayRemotePushNotification(payload)

}

//Setup Sinch pushKit------------------------------------------
func managedPush(_ managedPush: SINManagedPush!, didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload payload: [AnyHashable : Any]!, forType pushType: String!) {
    print("Getting poush notif")

    return
}

func client(_ client: SINCallClient!, localNotificationForIncomingCall call: SINCall!) -> SINLocalNotification! {
    print("Getting local notif")
    let notif = SINLocalNotification()
    notif.alertAction = "Missed call"
    notif.alertBody = "Incoming call"
    return notif
}
```

I’m pretty sure I have Since set up properly because `didReceiveIncomingCall` is called when the app is open.

So my question is, when user A calls user B, do I have to call any other function to ensure that user B gets notified when the app is in terminated state? Simply calling `callUser` doesn’t seem to work..

Comment: VoipPush certificate or normal APNS?

Comment: figured it out, thanks!

Comment: Maybe to help others can you explain what the error was?

Comment: hey @ChrisJones, I am facing the same issue. can you post your solution. Thanks!

Comment: @ParthBhuva check whether you're using Dev or Production in the AppDelegate when you initialize it

Comment: @ChrisJones, Found the solution. for call in background, I was missing delegate implementation "willReceiveIncomingCall". Thanks

Comment: please can someone help me I am stuck on this